# Benefits and drawbacks of using .io TLD as Java package?

Tags: java, package, tld

I know we can name Java packages almost anything, but I wanted to ask if using the `.io` TLD has any particular benefits or drawbacks in the community.

Originally people named Java packages by company, e.g. `com.example.acme.foobar`. Later it became common to give an open-source community project a separate `.org` name, e.g. `org.jooq` hosted on `jooq.org`.

Nowadays certain circles (e.g. the JavaScript / GitHub communities) seem to enjoy creating sites using the `.io` TLD, e.g. http://atom.io. And I agree that's a clever nomenclature, so I'm considering using it for my own open-source Java project.

But has this gained much acceptance in the Java community? If I name my package `io.foobar` will that cause more confusion than help? Will it appear that it is an I/O related library even though it isn't? Will it cause any problems with tools or build systems? Anything I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small projects, the package namespacing and the Maven groupId usually coincide, so let's assume they're the same thing for this answer:

There are currently 383 [`io.*` TLDs](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io) hosted on Maven central as opposed to 2245 [`org.*` TLDs](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/) or a whooping 3520 [`com.*` TLDs](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/).

I'd say, `io.*` is a minority, but given the fact that it is only a recent practice to use `io` TLDs at all, I think you're following a popular trend. Go for it!

Comment: A helpful response, Lukas---thanks! But you may not have noticed that you actually answered a _different_ question, namely: "Should I use an `.io` TLD for my Maven groupId?" Yes, by default one would think that they would be the same, but I (as always) can't help but first ponder the default answer before accepting it. If I have a FooBar project, using a groupId of `io.foobar` would give me coordinates of `io.foobar:foobar:1.0`, which is repetitive. It would be possible to have a package of `io.foobar` with Maven coordinates of `com.example.acme:foobar:1.0`, for example. I'm still undecided.

Comment: @GarretWilson: You're right. I assumed that package prefixes and Maven groupIds are the same thing, because they mostly are in most small projects. E.g. if you have `com.example.acme:foobar:1.0`, then your package names are most likely something like `com.example.acme.foobar`, not `io.foobar` except perhaps for historic reasons. Anyway, you have a valid point, I really just answered your question *"But has this gained much acceptance in the Java community?"* where I understood *"this"* being using the `io` TLD at all.

Comment: Lukas, thanks for your discussion and insight into this question. Your contribution played a large part in helping me come to a decision. In the end I decided to go with `.io` for the domain, the Maven groupId, and the Java package. In fact I just finished releasing [Csar](http://csar.io/) and [Rincl](http://rincl.io), two projects using this naming approach. They are now available via Maven Central at [io.csar](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22io.csar%22) and [io.rincl](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22io.rincl%22), respectively.